# run multiinstance of geckowebbrowser on multiinstances of 1 form

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I want to run a number of instances of 1 form on which i have a dynamically GeckoWebBrowser and some automated tasks but every time i create a new instance of form other GeckoWebBrowser become inactive and only the latest created GeckoWebBrowser works
Help!

```
    Dim f As New Form2
    f = New Form2
    f.Show()
```

my Code on Form2

```
    Imports Gecko
Public Class Form3
    Friend WithEvents w As New GeckoWebBrowser
    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        w = New GeckoWebBrowser
        Dim n As Integer = 100
        For i = 0 To n
            w.Navigate("http://google.com")
            'do some stuff here
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You will need to post the code of `Form2`, and explain how you can tell that the browsers are not working. It is not possible to help with what you have posted so far.

Comment: @RobertBaron edited , tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the same behavior as your. I found a solution. You will probably need to adapt it to your need. I do not know why it behaves like this, but it has something to do with the application messages pump. Anyway, here is how I got it to work.

Create `Form1` with a single button to launch `Form2` instances.

[image]

And the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New Form2
        f.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create `Form2` with the Gecko WebBrowser, and a button that will start the naviagation in the WebBrowser.

[image]

And the code:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form2

    Private _stack As New Stack(Of String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To 100
            _stack.Push("http://google.com")
            _stack.Push("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
        Next
        GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(_stack.Pop())
    End Sub

    Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(_stack.Pop())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Open several instances of `Form2` by clicking the `New Form` button on `Form1`. Click the `Start` button on `Form2`. This will populate a stack of urls to be navigated to, and navigate to the first url on the stack. Once navigation to each link is completed, the `DocumentCompleted` event handler triggers the navigation to the next link.

As I said, you will have to adapt this solution to your needs.

Comment: @Meisam Hashemi - Did that help?